# TeXstudio: what does the "Long Range Repetitions" setting do?

Tags: texstudio

I am trying to adjust TeXstudio's settings so that it only highlights a word which is repeated immediately immediately (like I just did). "Aardvark Banana Aardvark" should not be highlighted.

My TeXstudio settings page looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

What is a "Long Range Repetition"? How is it different from a regular repetition? My best guess is that:

- **Words Between Repetitions = 3** means that the second Aardvark is flagged in "Aardvark 1 2 3 Aardvark" but not in "Aardvark 1 2 3 4 Aardvark"
- **Min Length of Words with Long Repetition = 6** means that "12345" would be ignored when searching for long range repetitions, but "123456" would not

But **Long Range Repetitions = 10** is completely opaque to me. If I want to turn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording is a bit confusing but apparently "long range" means "long words", so words with a minimal length (as specified in the option below).

From https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/master/src/configdialog.ui:

> Equal words are marked as repetition if there are no more than this
> number of words between them.
>
> Equal, longer words are marked as long range repetition if there are
> no more than this number of words between them.
>
> Only words with have this length are checked for long range
> repetitions.